# mysql: datetime displays 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: mysql, hibernate, datetime

I have taken use of Hibernate and mysql to work coding

Entity class is:

```
@Column(name="CREATE_TIME")
private Date createTime; 
@Column(name="UPDATE_TIME")
private Date updateTime; 
@Column(name="DELETE_TIME")
private Date deleteTime;
```

Controller write as below:

```
user.setCreateTime(DateUtil.getCurrentDate());
result = userService.addOrUpdateUser(user);
```

DaoImpl write as:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.saveOrUpdate(user);
session.flush();
```

My trouble is:
    the result saved in mysql is:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Why does it show like that ,and i hava add **zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull** in mysql url?